# Covert RGB data to YUV420P format

Tags: opengl-es

I want to convert RGB packed data to YUV420P format using fragment shader. How do I get shader output in a planar format.

I am not really getting how can I make fragment shader to output in planar format.
I am new to OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

With standard OpenGL ES you can't - it has no concept of YUV.

With extensions, if you have a device that supports the `GL_EXT_YUV_target` extension you can write into an YUV buffer that is imported.

- https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_YUV_target.txt

... although exactly what is supported is implementation-defined.